# Finding Elements Relatively by XPath

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am writing a method to find the parent element  of any given element by XPath. I'm really baffled as to why this does not work.

```
protected WebElement findParent(WebDriver driver, WebElement element) {
    return driver.findElement(By.xpath("parent::*"));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try invoking [**WebElement.findElement**](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)) using your `element` argument rather than [WebDriver.findElement](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)) using your `driver` argument.  In fact, you might as well just drop the `driver` argument as it's not needed if you have the element for which you want to retrieve the parent:

```
protected WebElement findParent(WebElement element) {
    if (element == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return element.findElement(By.xpath(".."));
    }
}
```

Also, your `"parent::*"` XPath should work fine, but I'd suggest the idiomatic `".."` (as mentioned by @alecxe) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use `..` xpath expression:

```
return element.findElement(By.xpath(".."));
```

Answer (score 1):

To be explicit, you can use:

```
return driver.findElement(By.xpath("self::*/parent::*"));
```

I find this to be more obvious when reading the code. However, I could not say if there are any performance differences between this and ".."

Comment: This won't work. The `driver` instance has no context element. You probably meant to use `element.findElement()`.

Comment: Sorry, I too assumed the original post was calling "findElement" on an element! Apologies, next time I shall read the question fully!